# Gimp won't launch properly from a shell script in OSX

Tags: python, macos, shell, gimp

I'm using MacOS Mojave (v. 10.14.16, latest version with all updates) and I'm running Gimp 2.10. I made a Python plugin that works great from the command line terminal, but I can't it to work from a shell script. The plugin opens an XCF template, adds an external JPG as a new layer, positions the external JPG using x and y offsets, flattens, and then exports a new JPG that shows the external JPG in the template.

Background info:

In OSX just typing “gimp” at a terminal did not launch Gimp, so I created an alias in the .bash_profile in my home directory (/users/TimB) using the steps described here: https://mattmazur.com/2012/01/27/how-to-add-terminal-aliases-in-mac-os-x-lion/. The alias reads as follows:

```
alias gimp=”/Applications/GIMP-2.10.app/Contents/MacOS/gimp”
```

My alias works great from the command line terminal, but not from a shell script.

In my shell script just trying to execute “gimp” on a line does not launch Gimp so I believe my alias is not recognized in the script. Therefore, to launch Gimp along with my Python command line arguments I do this:

```
/applications/gimp-2.10.app/contents/macos/gimp -idf --batch-interpreter python-fu-eval -b "import sys;sys.path=['.']+sys.path;import OAFE_PARAM;OAFE_PARAM.open_add_flatten_export('/Users/TimB/Desktop/xcftemplate.xcf', '/Users/TimB/Desktop/jpg_to_add.jpg', 2060, 410, '/Users/TimB/Desktop/')" -b "pdb.gimp_quit(1)"
```

This does not work. My command line arguments are ignored, and I see a message "GIMP-Warning: The batch interpreter 'python-fu-eval' is not available. Batch mode disabled."

To troubleshoot I tried just launching the Gimp UI from a shell script and even that doesn't work properly. It loads strangely with broken icons (see image below). Any ideas what I can do to fix this? Am I doing something wrong in how I'm trying to launch Gimp?

[Gimp UI screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zmetp.jpg)

Here's my script to launch Gimp that fails:

```
#!/bin/bash

arg1="/Users/TimB/Desktop/xcf_template.xcf"  #XCF file to open
arg2="/Users/TimB/Desktop/jpg_to_add.jpg" # JPG to insert
arg3=2060        # x_offset
arg4=410         # y_offset
arg5="/Users/TimB/desktop/" # save location
echo 
echo "arg1 is" $arg1
echo "arg2 is" $arg2
echo "arg3 is" $arg3
echo "arg4 is" $arg4
echo "arg5 is" $arg5

/applications/gimp-2.10.app/contents/macos/gimp -idf --batch-interpreter python-fu-eval -b "import sys;sys.path=['.']+sys.path;import OAFE_PARAM;OAFE_PARAM.open_add_flatten_export('/Users/TimB/Desktop/xcftemplate.xcf', '/Users/TimB/Desktop/jpg_to_add.jpg', 2060, 410, '/Users/TimB/Desktop/')" -b "pdb.gimp_quit(1)"
```

**UPDATE (3-27-2021):**
I followed Mark's suggestion by removing my alias, ensuring that /usr/local/bin is on my PATH, and I created a symlink with sudo ln -s /applications/gimp-2.10.app/contents/macos/gimp /usr/local/bin/gimp. That still lets me launch Gimp by typing "Gimp" in terminal, but it still fails from within a shell script. I get this message.

The shell script is very simple:

```
#!/bin/bash
gimp
```

Here's the error I get:

```
../../../../gtk/source/babl-0.1.78/babl/babl-internal.h:214 void babl_log(const char *, ...)()
    WARNING: the babl installation seems broken, no extensions found in queried
BABL_PATH (/Users/distiller/gtk/inst/lib/babl-0.1) this means no SIMD/instructions/special case fast paths and
only slow reference conversions are available, applications might still
run but software relying on babl for conversions will be slow

2021-03-27 11:27:22.180 gimp[85955:1451980] *** WARNING: Method userSpaceScaleFactor in class NSView is deprecated on 10.7 and later. It should not be used in new applications. Use convertRectToBacking: instead. 
Cannot spawn a message bus without a machine-id: Unable to load /var/lib/dbus/machine-id or /etc/machine-id: Failed to open file “/var/lib/dbus/machine-id”: No such file or directory
../../../../gtk/source/babl-0.1.78/babl/babl-internal.h:222 void babl_fatal(const char *, ...)()
    const Babl *babl_format(const char *)("CIE Lab double"): not found
sh: gdb: command not found
```

Comment: Maybe you could be more precise about a) **how** you made the alias, b) **where** you made the alias - in Terminal, in your `~/.profile`, somewhere else? c) what **exactly** doesn't work. And maybe say what your Python GIMP-fu actually does, because you might find it all easier with **ImageMagick**, or macOS built-in `sips` or **Python**.

Comment: I made the alias in my .bash_profile using the instructions here https://mattmazur.com/2012/01/27/how-to-add-terminal-aliases-in-mac-os-x-lion/. My script opens an XCF Gimp template, inserts a JPG as a new layer, repositions the new layer (the values above are X and Y offsets), then flattens and exports a new JPG. I plan to repeat this for many images by invoking from the shell script. Unfortunately I do not believe ImageMagick is an option because it doesn't do layers.

Comment: Mmmm... beware of anyone who writes `cd ~` which is unnecessarily vebose and doesn't work in all shells, unlike plain `cd`. Anyway, rather than vaguely describe what you did in the comments, please click `edit` under your question and add in **exactly** what you did. Thank you. Also, I don't follow your comments about **ImageMagick** not handling layers. You appear to be exporting a JPEG which doesn't support layers so the question of *"layer support"* is surely moot? Please try to be more specific about all the issues so folks can assist you better. Thank you.

Comment: Original post has been updated.

Comment: `OS X` became `macOS` five years ago in 2016. Could you be more precise as to what OS you are actually running please? Also, you say at 2) that your shell script doesn't work. Please be more precise about a) how your shell script looks, b) how you invoke it and c) what doesn't work? Thank you.

Comment: Original post updated again.

Comment: I would be inclined to remove altogether your aliases, and ensure `/usr/local/bin` is on your PATH and create a symlink with `sudo ln -s /applications/gimp-2.10.app/contents/macos/gimp /usr/local/bin/gimp`

Comment: Ugh! It looks like GIMP doesn't fit too well in the macOS ecosystem. I don't know what to suggest, sorry. I just tried on my machine and I get the same error. I tried installing `babl` with **homebrew** but that didn't help. I found it works somewhat better if you change directory to `/Applications/GIMP...` before running it which, to my mind, is another indication it isn't very well integrated into macOS.

Comment: Maybe I can persuade you to reconsider **ImageMagick**. It is just `brew install imagemagick` with **homebrew**. If you want to paste `overlay.png` onto `background.jpg` at offset 2040,610, it is just `magick background.jpg overlay.png -geometry +2040+610 -composite result.jpg`.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error today on macOS 12.4, Monterey. Gimp and babl installed through brew. Even when I run it as:

```
BABL_PATH=/usr/local/lib/babl-0.1 gimp
```

it still fails.

```
../babl/babl-internal.h:222 void babl_fatal(const char *, ...)() const Babl *babl_model(const char *)("RGBA"): you must call babl_init first
Unable to find Mach task port for process-id 17902: (os/kern) failure (0x5).
(please check gdb is codesigned - see taskgated(8))
/tmp/babl.gdb:1: Error in sourced command file:
No stack.
```

The gdb error is not related. I just didn't sign it yet. If I start gimp by clicking on the icon then it works though. But not from the cmdline.

Comment: Seeing the same issue here today on macOS 12.6 Monterey.